# E6410 latitude won't sleep

Tags: sleep, dropbox, dell-latitude

E6410 when I hit sleep will black the screen and show HD and wifi lights indefinitely. Never gets to sleep. Have to power off and on.

This seems to be affected by Dropbox; when I disable it before hibernating or sleeping, it goes down just fine...

Comment: operating system?

Comment: Win 7 32 bit pro.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's Dropbox, as far as I can tell. I found this on a dell forum as a batch file you can run to hibernate the computer:

```
taskkill /f /im Dropbox.exe /t
%windir%\System32\rundll32.exe powrprof.dll,SetSuspendState
cd C:\Users\YOURUSERNAME\AppData\Roaming\Dropbox\bin
start Dropbox.exe
```